# Not all the rows are printed from my CSV file

Tags: python, csv, while-loop

Not all the rows are print from my CSV file, it's only printing the first row and going back to the `while` loop again. I want to add another function right after to print all the rows, but it's not working for some reason.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import stdiomask

def volleyball_court():
    print("Volleyball Courts")
    print()
    with open("location.csv", "r") as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        location = (input("Enter your suburbs:")
        for row in csvreader:
            if location in str(row[0]):
                print(row)
                return_menu()
```

Comment: I think you have a typo. return.menu() should be return_menu()

Comment: yeah i have changed it but its still not working

Comment: When the `volleyball_court()` function is called, it will only print one row of the CSV because of the `return.menu()` it contains (which I assume is actually `return_menu()`). I think that should be unindented so it's at the same level as the `for` loop.

Comment: It'll only print location if the location is the same as what the user enters, correct?

Comment: Can you include a sample of your locations.csv?

Comment: I have just uploaded my full code please have a look at this.

Comment: I think he means the actual csv data. You can copy and past a few rows.

Comment: done its at the bottom of the codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling return_menu() in your if statement, move that out of the for loop and you should be ok.

```
for row in csvreader:
    if location in str(row[0]):
        print(row)
return_menu()
```